# Audio skips and jitters/lags or plays super fast typically on first attempt to play audio from device

Tags: android, flutter, audio, just-audio

I've tried to play an mp3 file stored on device(not an asset) via android emulator with just_audio and audio_players packages and in both cases on first attempt to play the file the first 5-10 are typically super glitchy and stuttery or the audio is playing super fast and then after 10-20 seconds it plays normally and subsequent playthroughs will be perfect. The audio is only about 45seconds. I have tried increasing playback buffer and make sure the audioplayers says its ready before playing and neither makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tested whether the problem also happens when opening the same file in other apps?

Comment: @RyanHeise So I ditched the emulators and ran it on my pixel 6 pro and audio sounded great. So I'm guessing its an emulator problem i was using Nexus 6 API 30 emulator. I will try with a few other emulators to see it happens for all of them. It's definitely not an issue with the audio file itself as I have tried many both from urls and local path and all have had the same issue.